# Performing a Promise.all with parameters

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, promise

I'm trying to create an Array of Promises I'd like to fulfill however not sure how to best loop through them.

I thought the following code was doing the trick but it appears when I create the array of promises I'm actually calling them as a side effect, which is not what I want to do until Promise.all is hit.

```
import wait from 'waait'

const main = async () => {
    console.log('Start')
    const doStuff = async (name) => {
        console.log('Do stuff called', name)
        await wait(500)
        return name + ' is cool'
    }


    const names = ['Dan', 'Mitchell', 'Josh']

    const promises = names.map(name => doStuff(name))

    // const data = await Promise.all(promises)
    // console.log(data)
    console.log('End')
}

main()
```

I am finding that with the last two lines getting commented out, the doStuff function appears to be getting called as the console.log is happening in my console.

I was expecting the behaviour of the promises created in the map to remain in a drafted state and then called upon in Promise.all but this isn't the case.

Can someone explain and offer an explanation as to how this should be done?

Answer (score 3):

A promise starts immediately when it is created. There is no "start()" method, thus all you have to do is make sure you only create promises when you need them. I would wrap the call to create your promises in an `async` function that is only called when the promises should be created, and then `await` on `Promise.all()` inside that function, as you were intending.

You may also consider wrapping promises in async functions and creating an array of async functions instead - except you will still need to loop over the array and call each function to retrieve the created promises and wait on them. Perhaps something like:

```
var pending = names.map(n => async ()=>await doStuff(n));  // (warning: untested; off the top of my head)
```

Then you have an array of pending promises wrapped in functions. When the time comes you can use `var promises = pending.map(f=>f())` to call the functions and create an array of promises.

Comment: Wouldn't that be wrapping several promises in one big promise?

Comment: It’s either that or wrap each promise in an async function and create an array of async functions instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the promises inside `Promise.all()`:

```
const names = ['Dan', 'Mitchell', 'Josh']

const data = await Promise.all(names.map(name => doStuff(name)));
console.log(data);
```

Comment: When I run that and comment out await Promise.all(promises) it still runs 3 times.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I edited my post to reflect the changes. If I remember correctly there is no native way to keep the promises in "pending" but I recall there were packages to do it, although I would prefer it this way.

Comment: A criteria is this `expecting the behaviour of the promises created in the map to remain in a drafted state`. You are just creating a shortcut for the same thing.